# Referring to subsequent cells in CountIf

Tags: excel, vba, countif

After an extensive and ineffectual google search, I'm hoping someone can help me out:
I want to count the occurrences in a column of cells where a cell is greater than the cell that follows it, i.e.:

_A
1 2
2 1
3 2
4 1

Would return a countif of 2 as A1>A2, and A3>A4.

I also want to refer to offsets from the current cell being checked in the form of something like (with intentions in braces):

```
=countif(A:A, [Current cell being checked] ">" [Cell below the current cell being checked])
```

I can't seem to drum up these types of this. references. I know I could write a quick macro to do this but I'm interested in knowing this method of referencing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't compare one range with another with COUNTIF

You could use `SUMPRODUCT` like this:

`=SUMPRODUCT((A1:A3>A2:A4)+0)`

or more generically

`=SUMPRODUCT((Range>OFFSET(Range,1,0))+0)`

Comment: Thanks for the help! The generic version seems to work. Is there any way to reference the "active" cell of a range checking function within a cell formula?

Comment: Not sure what you mean - This formula will refer to the current cell of a vertical range `=INDEX(range,ROW()-MIN(ROW(Range))+1)` but it depends what you want to do - you may get a circular reference

Comment: I was hoping for an in formula version of the ActiveCell present in VBA, or a JAVA style this.cell call, that allows relative shifts like offset or vlookups to obtain values for an expression, and that reevaluates as the Active Cell shifts. Although just reading it and knowing the functions styles of passing Ranges doesn't make this seem possible...